# Unable to resolve path dependent type class evidence w/o having value type accessible

Tags: scala, implicit, scalac, path-dependent-type

I got stuck for like an hour to discover this fact:

```
class Foo {
  trait TypeClass[X]
  object TypeClass {
    implicit val gimme = new TypeClass[Int]{}
  }

  def foo[X : TypeClass](p: X): Unit = println("yeah " + p)
}

    // compiles
val foo = new Foo()
foo.foo(4)

    //does not compile
new Foo().foo(4)

    could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type _1.TypeClass[Int]
    [error]   new Foo().foo(4)
    [error]
```

I can't figure out why that is. The only thing that I can think of is that scalac doesn't find implicits within a Type that doesn't have a Value Type accessible on any prefix. It cannot be referenced. Scalac apparently needs to access that `Foo.this.foo` to resolve implicits in it, which it can't in this case.

I feel like that if you combine type classes and path dependent types, you are effectively doomed. You'll end up dealing with this kind of stuff. I did that because scalac wouldn't otherwise infer types in my API methods and user would have to declare them explicitly. So I chose this kind of design so that types are constructed in `Foo[T]` and api methods use the existing type, but I hit several really ugly problems and bugs of this kind that made my app look like an overengineered crap...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path dependent types may be bound only to some stable immutable values, so the more obvious  example also will not work, because immutability is not guaranteed:

```
scala> var foo = new Foo()
foo: Foo = Foo@4bc814ba

scala> foo.foo(4)
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type    _37.TypeClass[Int]
          foo.foo(4)
                 ^

scala> def foo = new Foo()
foo: Foo

scala> foo.foo(4)
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type _39.TypeClass[Int]
          foo.foo(4)
                 ^
```

`_37` means that type was not inferred. So, it seems like scala simply infer type only after it's assigned to some `val`. It's not related to implicits actually, this will give you the more clear explanation:

```
scala> class C {type K = Int}
defined class C

scala> var z = new C
z: C = C@4d151931

scala> def aaa(a: z.K) = a
<console>:16: error: stable identifier required, but z found.
   def aaa(a: z.K) = a
              ^

scala> def z = new C
z: C

scala> def aaa(a: z.K) = a
<console>:16: error: stable identifier required, but z found.
   def aaa(a: z.K) = a
              ^
```

Your `new Foo` expression is similar to `def newFoo = new Foo`, so there it's considered as unstable.

Comment: so the last snippet of mine has an immutable identifier that is not stable because it is in a method scope, so that doesn't work either? `  def method() = { // this doesn't compile either if it is within a method scope
    val foo = new Foo()
    foo.foo[Int](4)
  }'

Comment: actually last snippet works for me - Scala REPL 2.11.2

Comment: I also declared it inside of object (see update in my answer) and ran/compiled using scala/scalac - and it works

Comment: But here you declared implicit val inside class itself - implicits doesn't work that way (they should be defined inside companion object), see http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html. Or just `import foo._`

Comment: Ups, I forgot it this way when I was playing with it, sorry... Thank  you dk14, you got it.